# error:"File is used by another process" while generating document in openxml

Tags: c#, ms-word, openxml

I’m generating word document using open xml(using copy stream).When multiple users click the generate button at the same time it is throwing an error”File is used by another process” .How to prevent it?please help!

Comment: Make sure every user uses a different filename.

Comment: Show the full code (about saving/copying/opening/...). It's possible that a temp file is used somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

A single file can not be generated by multiple user. Possible solutions:
1. Create the file with different name for different users.
2. Ensure mutual Exclusion using `Mutex`
3. Make sure that you are closing memoryStream after use. Otherwise it will be open in memory.

Comment: thanks fr the reply.the file name is already different for different users

Answer (score 0):

The Files of each user should have different names, e.g. by naming them like

```
filename += "_"+Environment.MachineName;
```

Comment: thanks fr the reply.the file name is already different for different users.

Answer (score -2):

thanks fr the reply.the file name is already different for different users.I have assigned the filename as the name of the user (from session) and along with current date and time .so eventually filename is different for differrent users

Comment: Don't post a comment as an answer. Add a comment or _edit_ your question.

Comment: And then you can delete this answer.